# Can OpenLayers 3 properly render KML?

Tags: openlayers-3

When I used the simple online Demo (http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/examples/drag-and-drop.html), and dropped in a KML file, it got the colors right but it ignored all the placemarks. Using Ubuntu+Chrome.

My needs are pretty basic - I want to make a simple Web page, which allows the user to click one of a number of links, and then render KML corresponding to that link. I would love to use OL3 instead of Google My Maps + Maps, if only because Google appears to require a credit card # etc, for the privilege of using their Javascript API(s).

Thanks!

Comment: The KML definition is fairly open and vast. It is impossible for OpenLayers or any other library to support everything in the KML definition. Is the KML you are trying to drop publicly accessible? Or can you provide an extract with a feature that OpenLayers does not read. By the way... I am using the Google Maps API for years without ever giving Google my credit card details. You only need to register if you require the service upwards of a certain threshold.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!

If I understand you correctly, <Placemark> is not (necessarily) meaningful to OpenLayers 3, or to any other KML viewer other than Google Maps.

The KML is publicly available. Example: http://www.ercot.com/content/cdr/contours/rtmLmpHg.kml

Btw I would love to know how you are using the Maps API. I followed their tutorial at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial, and step 1 has me visiting the Google Developers Console, creating an API key, etc. Happy to know another way :)

Comment: You need an API key. But you don't need a credit card to obtain the API key. Do you have a google account to access https://console.developers.google.com/ ? Then just create an empty project and enable the Google Maps API.

Comment: I gotta have to take the dog for a walk. I will look at the KML tomorrow if nobody else gets back to you before.

Comment: Dennis - I just went to that Google Developers Console link, and I created a project and looks like I have an API key. Which is great.

Thanks so much for taking the time to get me on the right track. Btw how do you like the Maps API?

Comment: I am not a big fan of the Maps API. Its good for what it is. But OL provides a vast amount of features and the source code. If something doesn't work in Google Maps you are often left on your own. The OL community is better and more helpful. Plus, I excessively use Geoserver and the WFS format. You won't have that with the Google Maps API.

Comment: OL (and its community) sound pretty great. I'm glad I had enough of an issue with Google Maps API, to make me look into OL in the first place. I have a demo to deliver by Monday, for which Google Maps will get the job done. After that I will be taking a hard look at OL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/goldrydigital/n1vn7c8e/).

You should be able to drag and drop that example KML file which you provided.

[image]

The problem is not the placemarks. Placemarks are fine for OL3. My feeling is that you don't see that data in the other example because the styles are read from the KML. Reading styles from a KML and trying to put this into OL3 opens a whole can of worms.

So I recommend to first use:

```
formatKML = new ol.format.KML({extractStyles: false});
```

Comment: I wrote the jsFiddle specifically for the file in the comments of the question. This is a very crude example and may not work with other KML files. I assume that the input coordinates are EPSG:4326 as in the given example.

Comment: Thanks! It does indeed accept the KML just fine. So it sounds like Maps happens to know exactly how to read the styles in this KML file. Ultimately that's not what I want - I don't like how Maps renders the info, and I was hoping to control that myself. Sounds like that might actually be a job for OL3.

Comment: It is. The styling with OL3 is actually very good. Much improved to OL2. You can write style rules based on the properties of the features.